# Precision of SVG coordinates?

Tags: browser, svg, coordinates, precision, specifications

Does anyone know the "official" precision of SVG coordinates in browsers?

For example: If I draw [an arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) with almost 360° it will eventually disappear because start and end are collapsing.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
        path {
            stroke-width: 10px;
            stroke: black;
            fill: none;
        }
    </style>
    <path 
        d="
        M 200 200
        A 100 100 0 1 1 199.99999 199.99999"
    />
</svg>
```

draws a perfect circle (in Firefox 34). However, adding a `9` to `199.99999` yields to nothing being drawn. Is this behavior specified anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG specification says [double precision](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/conform.html#ConformingSVGViewers). No UA implements this though because they are all constrained by platform capabilities such as direct3d which are generally single precision.

Comment: But `199.999999` is still far away from single precision.

Comment: It is and that's a cairo limitation most likely: http://cairographics.org/documentation/ it has fixed point precision i.e. 6 binary bits or one part in 256 (depends on whether you're one mac or linux or windows of course exactly what you get)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, in other words: It is specified, but no one is following it because of platform limitations.